# SetupDiEnumDriverInfo returns different results on Windows 7 and Windows 8 / 10

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, driver

I am debugging an application that should retrieve information about all smart card reader drivers installed on a Windows system.

The code below works on Windows 7 (64 bit):

```
QSet<QString> getSmartCardDriverModuleNames()
{
    QSet<QString> moduleNames;

    // the GUID for the smart card reader device setup class
    wchar_t deviceClassGuidString[] = L"{50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}";
    GUID deviceClass;
    CLSIDFromString(deviceClassGuidString, &deviceClass);

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&deviceClass, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (deviceInfoSet == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return moduleNames;
    }

    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    for (DWORD deviceIndex = 0;
         SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex,
                               &deviceInfoData);
         deviceIndex++)
    {
        if (SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfoData,
                                       SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER))
        {
            SP_DRVINFO_DATA_W driverInfoData;
            driverInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(driverInfoData);
            for (DWORD driverIndex = 0;
                 SetupDiEnumDriverInfo(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfoData,
                                       SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER, driverIndex,
                                       &driverInfoData);
                 driverIndex++)
            {
                // Omitted: get service name and add to moduleNames.
            }

            SetupDiDestroyDriverInfoList(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfoData,
                                         SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER);
        }
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoSet);
    return moduleNames;
}
```

This code correctly finds the installed drivers when run on Windows 7, but finds no driver at all on Windows 8 or Windows 10 (both 64 bit), even though some drivers are installed.

It turns out (by adding extra logging and debug code) that under Windows 8 and 10 the first call to `SetupDiEnumDriverInfo` fails. In this case, by adding a call to `GetLastError()` I get `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`, which is the normal behaviour expected when the end of the list is reached (see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So, no errors are detected, but the result is empty.

In the documentation of the Windows API I have found no changes from Windows 7 to Windows 8, 10, so no adaptation to the above code should be needed.

Have I overlooked something? Do you have any hint as to what I should check next?

Comment: Sometimes the device class for a particular device changes between Windows version.  Might be worth checking.  (I think you can look this up in Device Manager.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks for the hint. I have checked the device class under Windows 10 and it reports `{50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5g-0000f805f530}`, which is the same I use in my code.

Comment: The code *seems* OK, and it works for me on Windows 10 if I change the GUID to to the mouse driver class.  (I don't have any machines with smartcard devices to test it on.)  Perhaps Windows doesn't think the drivers that you've installed are sufficiently compatible with the device?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I would expect that the device class is indicated by the driver itself, but I really have no idea how it actually works internally. Anyway, Windows 7 does think these drivers are sufficiently compatible with the corresponding card readers. Windows 8 and 10 don't.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: "I would expect that the device class is indicated by the driver itself": What I mean is that you do not need to have a smartcard reader attached to your computer, you only need to install a driver, e.g. SCL01xG_INST_WIN_EN_V1.13.zip (http://support.identive-group.com/downloads.php?lang=de&open=driver). This driver gets detected by Windows 7 (even without an attached device) but is not detected by Windows 8.

Comment: As far as I can see, that code shouldn't return anything if there is no corresponding device attached to the system, since in that case there's nothing for `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` to return.  Some drivers install virtual devices though, so perhaps that's the reason.  You might want to see what information you can get about the device that's being found, there might be a clue there.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Do you mean these drivers might install virtual devices on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8?

Comment: If you're getting as far as calling SetupDiEnumDriverInfo, then there must be a device (physical or otherwise) for you to query.  So it probably isn't that simple.  But if there is no physical device present, that's an oddity that is worth investigating.  It might not turn out to be relevant, but "all knowledge is worth having".

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Could you reproduce the problem with the driver I have indicated above?